# Scheduling a meeting using the MS Teams with non o365 profile (connected to custom server) returns error FailedToGetCalendarFromOutlook

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, microsoft-teams

I'm attempting to schedule a meeting using the MS Teams add-in via our MAPI connector, which communicates with the Zimbra server, and I'm receiving the error shown below.
I can use the same user as the O365 user, and everything works fine with exchange profile that talks with exchange server.
I'm not sure what is missing or what needs to be done to get it working.
Any help would be most welcome

**09-08:15:31.943 PM 5 Info Microsoft.Teams.MeetingAddin.Scheduler.SchedulerService CreateMeetingAsync This is an on-behalf-of meeting for vikas.galande@synacor.com**
2021-06-09-08:15:31.943 PM 5 Info Microsoft.Teams.MeetingAddin.Settings.SettingsBase Lookup Returning default value True for EnableJsonContractResolver setting
2021-06-09-08:15:31.943 PM 5 Info Microsoft.Teams.MeetingAddin.JSONUtilsLogger GetJsonSerializerSettings JSONUtils created JsonSettings
2021-06-09-08:15:35.970 PM 29 Error Microsoft.Teams.MeetingAddin.Scheduler.SchedulerService CreateMeetingAsync Received an error response: Microsoft.Teams.MeetingAddin.Scheduler.MeetingErrorMessage, telemetryId: eaab2650-0599-4fab-ad7f-7821c2dddff2
2021-06-09-08:15:35.970 PM 29 Error Microsoft.Teams.MeetingAddin.Scheduler.SchedulerService CreateMeetingAsync Exception of Type SchedulerServiceException happened. telemetryId: eaab2650-0599-4fab-ad7f-7821c2dddff2
2021-06-09-08:15:35.970 PM 29 **Error Microsoft.Teams.MeetingAddin.Scheduler.SchedulerService CreateMeetingAsync
Message:Processing of the HTTP request resulted in an exception. Please see the HTTP response returned by the 'Response' property of this exception for details.,StatusCode=Forbidden,ErrorSubCode=FailedToGetCalendarFromOutlook**
2021-06-09-08:15:35.971 PM 5 Error Microsoft.Teams.MeetingAddin.Operation.NewMeetingOperation Error Message:Processing of the HTTP request resulted in an exception. Please see the HTTP response returned by the 'Response' property of this exception for details.,StatusCode=Forbidden,ErrorSubCode=FailedToGetCalendarFromOutlook
2021-06-09-08:15:35.971 PM 5 Info Microsoft.Teams.MeetingAddin.Errors.ScheduleErrorHandler DisplayError Displaying an error: Title=Microsoft **Teams, Message=Sorry, but we can’t connect to the server right now. Please try again later.**

Any help is much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Are you using any graph API for this or Any code? Share some more details about your scenario.

Comment: Hi @amol surywanshi please let us know if your issue has been resolved.

Comment: Hi @amol surywanshi please let us know if your issue has been resolved.

Comment: The issue is resolved. This is the issue with MS Teams user not having appropriate rights to see calendar.